# VLOOKUP not giving expected results (Google Sheets)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, match, vlookup, array-formulas

I'm trying to build an excel sheet and i want to retrieve the values in column J (Salida) who match the criteria in columns G and I (Comedor and Index). :

[image]

To achieve that goal I'm using this formula in cell K17;

```
=vLOOKUP(concatenate(G17;I17); G7:J; 4; FALSE)
```

Let's see what I'm getting step by step:

```
=CONCATENATE(G17;I17)  // This gives me "A1" as String 

=Type(G17) returns 2 //String
=Type(I17) returns 2 //String


G7:J // the complete range where my criteria columns are in first positions

4 // The column index starting from the beginning of the range (Salida)

False // Exact match
```

And the error I'm receiving is "A1" not found in VLOOKUP evaluation but I have no idea about what's going on. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(VLOOKUP(G17&I17; {G7:G&I7:I \ J7:J}; 2; 0))
```